# Persistent Notification Without Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager

I am currently developing an app which is using AlarmManager to start an intent to show to the user every x minutes.  I would also like a persistent notification in the status bar that shows the time until the next popup.  Is there a way to show a persistent notification without a background service. If not does it make sense to stop using the AlarmManager and just use the service to popup the intent every x minutes?

Essentially I need to ensure that an intent will be launched every x minutes even if the phone gets low on mem and that the notification remains in the status bar.  I would also like to be able to click on the notification to reset the timer that is counting down.  What is the best way to achieve these objectives?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 1):

To generate Notification try this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

// To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
// "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
 if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
 notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
 notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
 contentIntent);
 notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
 notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

 } else {
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
 context);
 notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
.setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
.setContentText(message).build();

 notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to start an ongoing notification from one of my app intents if my apps is ended though I am guessing the notification will disappear?

Comment: If you click on notification, it will disappear.But if there are multiple notifications and if you want to manually remove notification than use notificationmanager.cancelAll() method.